# Liquibase generateChangeLog throws exception: SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between ... in the INTERSECT operation

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I'm following Liquibase's tutorial on [adding Liquibase on an Existing project](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html). When I run:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=dbchangelog.xml --logLevel=info generateChangeLog
```

the command ends with the error (see full stacktrace below):

```
SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Hebrew_BIN" in the INTERSECT operation.
```

What am I missing? I'm using the latest Liquibase version (3.8.7).

Full stacktrace:

```
16:13:50.205 ERROR [liquibase.integration.commandline.Main]: Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Hebrew_BIN" in the INTERSECT operation.
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Hebrew_BIN" in the INTERSECT operation.
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:289)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1412)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:303)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:163)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Hebrew_BIN" in the INTERSECT operation.
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:287)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Hebrew_BIN" in the INTERSECT operation.
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.SchemaSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(SchemaSnapshotGenerator.java:97)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:66)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:69)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:316)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:107)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:60)
        at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:39)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:217)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:190)
        at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:229)
        at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:151)
        at liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:60)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
        ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Hebrew_BIN" in the INTERSECT operation.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQueryInternal(SQLServerStatement.java:619)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetFromInternalQueries(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:224)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getSchemasInternal(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:1292)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getSchemas(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:1227)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.SchemaSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseSchemaNames(SchemaSnapshotGenerator.java:130)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.SchemaSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(SchemaSnapshotGenerator.java:63)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error message indicates there are different and conflicting column collations in the query. My guess is the database and instance collation are different (`Hebrew_BIN` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`) which can cause problems with some tools and queries not coded to handle differing collations. Knowing nothing about liquidbase, I can't say if the problem can be fixed via liquidbase configuration or it's a problem with the tool without a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading the latest SQL-server driver, specifically version 8.2. It turned out I was using an (extremely) outdated driver that contained the bug described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/399571a0-483b-4d81-b134-bcc670d8a7c0/collation-problems-when-calling-databasemetadatagetschemas?forum=sqldataaccess). The bug has to do with the driver's `getSchemas` method that Liquibase calls during the `generateChangeLog` command as is seen in the stacktrace.